# How to detect bad Mifare Classic cards through signal quality?

Tags: signals, nfc, mifare

i have some trouble with writing mifare classic cards.

Is there a way to get the quality of the signal to find bad cards?

I tried several cards.
Some cards could be written without any problems, but some cards failed many times.
After a second try whey could be written.

Comment: As you don't specify the hardware you are using or any code, it's impossible to answer. There are also lots of clone mifare classic tags available that might not be the same quality genuine.